# Dealing with off-topic questions

Tags: support, flags, off-topic

I rarely see off-topic questions on Stackexchange sites, where I don't know how to handle them right . Stackoverflow f.e. has the flag option: "Because these questions are not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the help center."

But these type of questions I'm talking about don't fit even roughly to the available off-topic options. Because they aren't about programming at all or belong to another site of Stackexchange, where the proper site isn't available in the options too.

My question is how to deal with them properly in general?

- Use the flag option "other" with a comment?
- Simply downvote them?

Comment: "*I rarely see questions on Stackexchange sites, which are off-topic*" # really?

Comment: I rephrased it. Now the meaning of "rarely off-topic" should be more understandable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Use the flag option "other" with a comment?

Yes.

> Simply downvote them?

You're free to do that as well, if you want.  You shouldn't do this *instead* of closing an off topic question though.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the existing answers, there's something else;

You are close to 3000 reputation, at which point instead of flagging to close, you'll be voting to close. The options are similar. There is an Off Topic -> Other where you can type in a custom reason, such as:

> This question appears to be off-topic because it is about maintaining a Facebook page

(*twitch*)

so that's something to keep in mind for those situations.

Comment: Good to know this. I'm missing close votes a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Flag as inappropriate, *and* downvote.  If you do nothing else, at least flag the post as inappropriate.